# JS - RegExp for detecting ".-" , "-."

Tags: javascript, regex

I am bit confused with the RegExp I should be using to detect `".-", "-."` it indeed passes this combinations as valid but in the same time, `"-_","_-"` get validated as well. Am I missing something or not escaping something properly?

```
 var reg=new RegExp("(\.\-)|(\-\.)");
```

Actually seems any combination containing `'-'` gets passed. it

Got it thank you everyone.

Comment: If you want to know the resulting expression, copy `RegExp("(\.\-)|(\-\.)")` in the console. The output is `/(.-)|(-.)/` and `.` matches any character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
"(\\.-)|(-\\.)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a string with the RegExp constructor rather than `/`, you need to escape twice.

```
>>> "asd_-ads".search("(\.\-)|(\-\.)")
3
>>> "asd_-ads".search(/(\.\-)|(\-\.)/)
-1
>>> "asd_-ads".search(new RegExp('(\\.\-)|(\-\\.)'))
-1
```

Comment: These are not `"` "delimiters". He needs to escape the ``\`` because he uses a **string** for the expression.

Answer (score 1):

In notation `/(\.\-)|(\-\.)/`, the expression would be right.
In the notation you chose, you must double all backslashes, because it still has a special meaning of itself, like `\\`, `\n` and so on.
Note there is no need to escape the dash here: `var reg = new RegExp("(\\.-)|(-\\.)");`

If you don't need to differentiate the matches, you can use a single enclosing capture, or none at all if you only want to check the match: `"\\.-|-\\."` is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

You are using double quotes so the `.` doesn't get escaped with one backslash, use this notation:

```
var reg = /(\.\-)|(\-\.)/;
```